# Using props inside of a field-array in redux-from

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form, react-props

I have a redux-form stateless component that contains a field array. I'm trying to determine how to pass a prop to a contained field in order to populate select list options.

```
 const renderSoftwareForm = ({ fields, meta: { error, submitFailed }, props}) => (
  <ul style={{listStyle: "none", padding: "0"}}>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
        Add Line Item
      </button>
    </li>
    {fields.map((softwares, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <Row>
        <Col sm={1}>
          <Field
            label="Theme"
            name={`${softwares}.theme`}
            type="select"
            component={SelectComponent}
          >
            <option>test</option>
            {props.themes.data && props.themes.data.map(themes => (
              <option value={themes.prodLine} key={themes.prodLineId}>
                {themes.prodLine}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Field>
        </Col>
        </Row>
        <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
          Remove Line Item
        </button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <span>&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

const SoftwareForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
  return (
    <div>
      <FieldArray name="softwares" props={props} component={renderSoftwareForm} />
    </div>
  )
}

  export default SoftwareForm;
```

Everything works with static values in the options list.

I can see the props being passed all the way to renderSoftwareForm, but it doesn't seem to be available inside of my Field... I feel like I'm missing something easy... props.themes.data returns an error --- Cannot read property 'themes' of undefined ---... How do I access this prop in the FieldArray Field?  [image: props passed image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Field
            label="Theme"
            name={`${softwares}.theme`}
            type="select"
            component={SelectComponent}
            props={{
              themes: props.themes 
           }}
          >
            <option>test</option>
            {props.themes.data && props.themes.data.map(themes => (
              <option value={themes.prodLine} key={themes.prodLineId}>
                {themes.prodLine}
              </option>
            ))}
          </Field>
```

This way themes props will be avaiilable in you selectComponent

Comment: I don't think that is valid syntax... props={
              themes: props.themes
            }

Comment: You are a hero! Thanks